# Anchor title at top of document

Tags: titles, titling

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[11pt, showframe]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%\usepackage{titling}
%\setlength{\droptitle}{-1.9cm}

\title{Curriculum Vitae}
\author{My name}
\date{August 2018}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

which produces the following output:

[image]

Is it possible to anchor/permanently set the title at the very top of the page (as close to the top border as possible)? I have tried to use the `titling` package, where I was able to place the title higher on the page. However, when I then would add/remove content from the page, the title would move as well. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two commented lines in your code give the expected result. However, I would not use ‘absolute’ units for `\droptitle`, but the font-dependent unit `ex`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{titling}
\setlength{\droptitle}{-11.5ex}

\title{Curriculum Vitae}
\author{My name}
\date{August 2018}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, @Bernard. I actually didn't know that there was a distinction between `ex` and `cm`, which is why I just always used the latter. Have a nice Sunday.

Comment: `ex` is the height of the letter xin the current font. I tested there's nothing to change whether the document font size be 10pt, 11pt  or 12 pt.